# Why does menu icon in NavigationView remain grey?

Tags: android, android-navigationview

I'm trying to tint my icons in the `NavigationView` menu. So, I write:

```
mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

And then I build my menu and set the tint for the icons:

```
Drawable baseIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.sh_filled_circle);
    Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();

    for (int i = 0; i < ts.size(); ++i) {
        Table.Timetable t = ts.get(i);
        MenuItem item = menu.add(R.id.timetable_menu, i, i, t.getTitle());
        item.setCheckable(true);
        Drawable fixedIcon = baseIcon.getConstantState().newDrawable().mutate();
        fixedIcon.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(t.getColor(),
                PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
        item.setIcon(fixedIcon);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? All the above code is in the `onCreate()` method of my `Activity`.

Comment: I found my error. I don't know that it doesn't work with shapes.